# Trying to connect to an AWS EC2 instance with a network interface that is disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

By mistake I disabled the only network interface that I had available in my instance, I know I can attach many public and internal network interfaces on a EC2 instance, so in the AWS console I chose from the EC2 menu `Networking->Add a new Network interface" but I get an error saying this:

> No available network interfaces were found for this VPC or
>   availability zone

So, my question is does this mean that I have to create the network interfaces inside of VPC and then attach it to this EC2 instance? If so, I did try that but I don't see any option inside of VPC where I can create a new network interface. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might have caused the error :

> No available network interfaces were found for this VPC or
>   availability zone

Solution to that is to make sure your instance is in your VPC in the public subnet. The subnet you are trying to connect to must be in the same availability zone as the instance.

---

**How to Restore Connectivity to Instance after disabling Network Interface**:

You will need to create a temporary Elastic Network Interface (ENI) and attach it to your instance. This will allow you to connect to the instance temporarily and fix the issue.

Steps are :

1. Select your instance, and make a note of what subnet its ENI is in.
2. [Create a new ENI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#create_eni) in the same subnet as the instance, selecting a security group that allows you to connect to your instance via SSH or RDP.
3. [Attach the new ENI to your instance.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#attach_eni_running_stopped)

**Note**: The new ENI might take a few minutes to come online. [Associate an Elastic IP address with the ENI.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#associate_eip)

4. Make sure that the security group associated with your instance allows inbound RDP connections or SSH Conenctions.
5. Using the new ENI, connect to your instance using RDP or SSH.
6. Re-enable the old network interface.
7. [Detach the temporary ENI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#detach_eni).

**Note**: If you’ve associated an Elastic IP address with the ENI, and no longer need the Elastic IP address, release it by following the instructions at [Releasing an Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-releasing) Address.

You Can refer to this [AWS Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3&v=umlK4uIxgd8)

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thank you, very well explained. I was able to resolve my issue before reading your answer and what I found was my problem is that I couldn't find the place to add a new ENI. I tried to search for that in the search input box from the console and I got nothing as result, so I finally found it and was able to solve the problem. Thank you for your answer!